# How to save more then one row in database using parse

Tags: android, database, storage, parse-server, back4app

I am new to parse SDK services using Android Studio and I have to ask that how to store more than one row in parse database . I am using back4app parse server whenever I want to put data on data base I.e more than one row then it does not store the first row but the second one as from the code below

```
ParseObject obj = new ParseObject("Table");
obj.put("Name","John");
obj.put("Score","40");
obj.put("Name","Jack");
obj.put("Score","50");
obj.saveInBackground();
```

So when I run app then only name and score for Jack stored in database creating one row and I want rows for both John and Jack, Kindly help me resolving this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You override your object fields ("name" and "score"), i.e. you delete `John` before save. Make a method that save your person:

```
private void savePerson(String name, String score){
    ParseObject obj = new ParseObject("Table");
    obj.put("Name",name);
    obj.put("Score",score);
    obj.saveInBackground();
}
```

and in code where you want to save person, call created method to do that:

```
savePerson("John", "40");
savePerson("Jack", "50);
```

Comment: Hey miljon first of all thanks for your reply but I watched in Rob Percival's android tutorial he saved with the same code as I mentioned in question and he got both rows at the same time as he executed the app and please describe the second approach you told me to do

Comment: Well you did something wrong if he did it and Its not working in your code ;) Still you override values.. Make a method to save a person and then just call it when you want to save a person, I edited answer look at it..